# Load ViewController inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, swift2, xcode7

I am loading a view controller as a subview inside of a uiscrollview. The following code works great until I try setting the value of an  @IBOutlet in the controller then the app crashes with the message

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This is my code:

```
let controller:ReportPageOneViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("report_page_one") as! ReportPageOneViewController
addChildViewController(controller)

controller.titleLabel.text = "This is some text. Hope it works"// App crashes here



detailsView.addSubview(controller.view)
view.addSubview(detailsView)
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure ( and not able to test...) but I think you should pass the text in a variable, and in the ReportPageOneViewController, viewWillAppear set the text to the titleLabel.text.

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I Am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone needing the solution, refer to the first comment above.

Create a new var titleValue = String

This should be in the view controller, then in the viewWillAppear set the outlet value to the variable

titleLabel.text = titleValue

In your main controller with the uiscroll view you can then set the variable value using controller.titleValue = "Anything you like"